# PDO Prepared Statement Causing Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql

i have checked this and I cant see the problem with it, although as seen below i'm getting an error. I've var_dump everything to ensure values are there.

Can someone please help?

**ERROR:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$word' in 'where clause'  on line 313

Comment: This has been changed,however K1 not being known>

Comment: @Cemal thanks Cemal. Made this change, however it's bringing nothing back for me at all.

Comment: well, the error should be gone, right?

Comment: yup, thx @chris85 for the typo. I add it as answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing prepared statements. You should parameterize the values so the driver will handle the data accordingly. So change:

```
$dbQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Meals where Category='Breakfast' AND Keyword=$Keyword");
$dbQuery->execute();
```

to:

```
$dbQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Meals where Category='Breakfast' AND Keyword=:Keyword");
$dbParams = array(':Keyword'=> $Keyword);
$dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
```

Comment: Perfect. Definitely better than mine.